# Protractor --version showing different version information?

Tags: node.js, protractor

I'm trying to update my protractor to v4.0.11 in order to hopefully fix an issue with browser.pause() not working correctly.

However `protractor --version` still shows the output of `2.5.1` after trying various installs `npm install protractor -g`, `npm install protractor@4.0.11 -g` and uninstalling/reinstalling protractor. After uninstalling, I could still get it to show `version 2.5.1`.

If would do `npm list grep protractor` it would give the correct information saying v4.0.11 is installed.

This lead me look around and see where it was finding the installed version.

Finally after comparing my path from `which protractor` to other co-workers, we've determined my Protractor is pointing to the wrong spot.

When I run `which protractor` I get the path result: `/c/Users/tso9955/AppData/Roaming/npm/protractor`.

When everyone else runs `which protractor` they get the path result:
`/c/program Files/nodejs/protractor`.

How or where do I tell it to use the Protractor installed at the `Program Files/nodejs/protractor` location?

Comment: Try uninstalling it using `npm rm protracor -g` and reinstall using `npm i protractor@4.0.11 -g`.Before reinstalling check whether protractor is uninstalled by typing `protractor --version`. if it shows the version that means it has not been removed properly. You have to manually delete it....Hope this helps